# Pickle on exiting application raises AttributeError

Tags: python, pyqt, pyside

I'm trying to pickle a class instance after the main application is closed but I'm getting

```
Exception AttributeError: "'NoneType' object has no attribute 'dump'" in <bound method MainFrame.__del__ of <__main__.MainFrame object at 0x03BA6508>> ignored
```

Here's a sample code:

```
from PySide.QtGui import *
import sys
import pickle

class Progress:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.x = value

    def __del__(self):
        pickle.dump(self, open("pickle_file.p", "wb"))


class MainFrame(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        QWidget.__init__(self)
        pass

    # def __del__(self):
    #     pickle.dump(progress, open("pickle_file.p", "wb"))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        with open("pickle_file.p", "r") as p_file:
            progress = pickle.load(p_file)
    except (EOFError, IOError):
        progress = Progress(1)

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    main = MainFrame()
    main.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Both methods of `__del__` raise the same error.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never use [`__del__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__del__) unless you really, *really* know what you're doing.

If you want to save things on exit, reimplement the [`closeEvent`](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#closeEvent) of the main window:

```
class MainFrame(QWidget):
    ...

    def closeEvent(self, event):
        pickle.dump(progress, open("pickle_file.p", "wb"))
```

Comment: plus 1 for linking to documentation of `__del__`